# ggplot2 and creation of name badges for an event

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I'm organizing the scientific conference and I stuck with simple problem. There will be around 300 participants during the conference and we need to create a name badge for everyone. The name badge has to be **50×85 mm**. The question is how to facet ggplot badge template keeping the resolution of the initial plot?

For example, this is the dataframe of participant's names:

```
names <- tibble(name = c("Jared Harris", "Stellan Skarsgеrd", "Paul Ritter",
                     "Jessie Buckley", "Adam Nagaitis", "Con O'Neill",
                     "Adrian Rawlins", "Sam Troughton", "Robert Emms",
                     "Emily Watson", "David Dencik", "Mark Lewis Jones",
                     "Alan Williams", "Alex Ferns", "Ralph Ineson",
                     "Barry Keoghan","Fares Fares", "Michael McElhatton"))
```

I've create a badge template and add some conference logos to it:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(grid)
library(magick)

# Donwload some sample logos
logo1 <- image_read("https://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/5cb58699cba3dd2a29200cb6.png")
logo2 <- image_read("https://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/5cb58635cba3dd2a29200caa.png")

# Create ggplot object
ggplot(data = names) +
  # Add participant's names
  geom_text(aes(label = str_wrap(string = str_to_upper(name),
                                 width = 15)),
            fontface = 2,
            x = 2.5, y = 1) +
  # Add conference name
  annotate("text", x = 2.5, y = 4,
           label = "3-6 september, 2019\nCity,\nName of the Conference") +
  # Add plot limits
  xlim(c(0, 5)) + ylim(c(0,8.5)) +
  # Specify theme
  theme_void() %+replace%
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, 
                                    colour = "grey60"),
        strip.text = element_blank()) -> p

# Add conference logos
p + annotation_custom(rasterGrob(logo1, interpolate=TRUE), 
                      xmin=3, xmax=5, ymin=6, ymax=8) +
  annotation_custom(rasterGrob(logo2, interpolate=TRUE), 
                    xmin=0, xmax=2, ymin=6, ymax=8) -> p
```

Cause I need to print it, I've saved it with default `pdf` function and awesome `ggplus`.

```
# Install ggplus
devtools::install_github("guiastrennec/ggplus")

pdf("badges/badges.pdf", paper = "a4", width = 31.35, height = 40.52)
ggplus::facet_multiple(plot = p, facets = "name", ncol = 3, nrow = 3) +
  annotation_custom(rasterGrob(msu, interpolate=TRUE), 
                    xmin=3, xmax=5, ymin=6, ymax=8) +
  annotation_custom(rasterGrob(mnks, interpolate=TRUE), 
                    xmin=0, xmax=2, ymin=6, ymax=8)
dev.off()
```

The result is like this:
[image]

Aaand here we face with the **first problem** — size of the each badge ***64.5×89.1*** mm, not desired ***50×85*** mm. How can I fix it?

**Secondly**, I'm living in Russia and I need to make badges in Russian. So If I'll change `names` dataframe to one containing Cyrillic letters like this:

```
names <- structure(list(name = c(
  "Айбулатов Денис Николаевич",
  "Александрин М.Ю.",
  "Александровский Алексей Юрьевич",
  "Андреев П.В.",
  "Антоненко М.В.",
  "Атутова Жанна Владимировна",
  "Бабич Дмитрий Борисович",
  "Баженова Ольга Иннокентьевна",
  "Бажин К.И.",
  "Барабанов Анатолий Тимофеевич")),
  row.names = c(NA,-10L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

All strings with Cyrillic letters shift for couple of inches to the right. And the question is — what the heck?

[image]

I'm using Windows machine and my session info is:

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251  LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[7] methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] magick_2.0      png_0.1-7       cowplot_0.9.4   extrafont_0.17 
 [5] forcats_0.3.0   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_0.8.1     purrr_0.3.1    
 [9] readr_1.3.1     tidyr_0.8.3     tibble_2.1.3    ggplot2_3.2.0  
[13] tidyverse_1.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1       cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.3.1    
 [4] compiler_3.5.1   tools_3.5.1      jsonlite_1.5    
 [7] lubridate_1.7.4  gtable_0.2.0     nlme_3.1-137    
[10] lattice_0.20-35  pkgconfig_2.0.2  rlang_0.3.4     
[13] cli_1.1.0        rstudioapi_0.8   curl_3.2        
[16] haven_2.1.0      Rttf2pt1_1.3.7   withr_2.1.2     
[19] xml2_1.2.0       httr_1.3.1       ggplus_0.1      
[22] generics_0.0.2   hms_0.4.2        tidyselect_0.2.5
[25] glue_1.3.1       R6_2.4.0         readxl_1.3.1    
[28] extrafontdb_1.0  modelr_0.1.2     magrittr_1.5    
[31] backports_1.1.3  scales_1.0.0     rvest_0.3.3     
[34] assertthat_0.2.1 colorspace_1.4-0 labeling_0.3    
[37] stringi_1.2.4    lazyeval_0.2.1   munsell_0.5.0   
[40] broom_0.5.1      crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: It's better to ask two separate question. (Also, you should switch to `ggforce` instead of `ggplus`.)